# How to stream audio from android device to a speaker via bluetooth that only supports SPP Profile?

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, spp, a2dp

Is it possible to stream an audio via bluetooth using SPP(Serial Port Profile)? Most of what I read, audio streaming is only possible via A2DP. And the problem is my audio output device only supports SPP.